# Organizing interfaces for player movement in chess game

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to organize interfaces in my game to make future development easier, by making my code more modular.

Notice that my `Rook` class implements the `IPlayer` interface, which will move it left and right, but not up and down (I had to add that in seperate methods). My question is, should I make an interface per method of movement that I want to do (IMoveLeft, IMoveRight, IMoveUp, IMoveDown)? This makes composing future players more modular, perhaps there is a better way.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPlayer bob = new Person();
            IPlayer rook = new Rook();
            List<IPlayer> iPlayerList = new List<IPlayer>();
            iPlayerList.Add(bob);
            iPlayerList.Add(rook);

            foreach (var player in iPlayerList)
            {
                player.MoveLeft(1);
                player.MoveRight(1);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Person : IPlayer
    {
        public int XDistanceFromOrigin { get; set; }

        public void MoveLeft(int distanceToMove)
        {
            XDistanceFromOrigin = XDistanceFromOrigin - 1;
        }

        public void MoveRight(int distanceToMove)
        {
            XDistanceFromOrigin = XDistanceFromOrigin + 1;
        }
    }

    interface IPlayer
    {
        void MoveLeft(int distanceToMove);
        void MoveRight(int distanceToMove);
    }

    public class Rook : IPlayer
    {
        public int XDistance { get; set; }
        public int YDistance { get; set; }

        public void MoveLeft(int distanceToMove)
        {
            XDistance = XDistance - 1;
        }

        public void MoveRight(int distanceToMove)
        {
            XDistance = XDistance + 1;
        }

        public void MoveUp(int distanceToMove)
        {
            YDistance = YDistance + 1;
        }

        public void MoveDown(int distanceToMove)
        {
            YDistance = YDistance - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the movement functions have actual implementations at the moment? If they do, I'd recommend including them just to make sure that this doesn't get closed as stub code.

Comment: @EthanBierlein, I abstracted that away from the code, because it is irrelevant to the question I was asking. Do you want me to include the using statements, and the namespace as well?

Comment: Well, in order for your question to be on topic, we'd need all the code for the methods. The using statements and the namespaces would also be helpful as well.

Comment: @EthanBierlein, ok, I'll try to be more explicit.

Comment: Maybe this would be better on another stackexchange site. Idk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A *player* doesn't move left or right, they move a *game piece*
2. A rook is not a player. A player *has a* rook (2 actually, but I digress).

When thinking about interfaces/class hierarchies it's useful to think in terms of "is a" or "has a" relationships. Bob *is a* player. A rook *is a* piece. A player *has a* rook.

I would modify your interfaces a bit.

```
interface IPlayer
{
    string Name { get; }
    bool MovePiece(IPiece piece, int row, int rank);
}

interface IPiece
{
    int Row { get; set; }
    int Rank { get; set; }

    bool CanMoveTo(int row, int rank);
}
```

You may want to consider using standard chess notation for clarity and cohesion with the problem domain, but using Cartesian coordinates will make the code simpler to write. I added a `CanMoveTo` method so each piece can store its own logic for checking to see if it's allowed to move to a position that the player attempts to move it to. This design may not be perfect (or even good), but should get you pointed in the right direction.